# How can I export the data in Xlxs format in Angular and i want to export the data such that the first row will be in Bold format?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, logic

// I want to download the above sheet in xlxs format in which the first row should be bold/

```
async downloadReport(): Promise<void> {const sheets = [];const dataRows = [];const payload = this.payloadService.payload['Journey1'];let response: any = this.reasonItems;response = [...new Map(response.map((item) => [item.sortData, item])).values()];
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {dataRows.push({'Column 1': response[i].data.barText,'Column 2': response[i].data.barData,'Column 3': '','Column 4': '','Column 5': '',});
```

```
for (let j = 0; j < response[i].top5.length; j++) {
  dataRows.push({
    'Column 1': '',
    'Column 2': '',
    'Column 3': response[i].top5[j].NotApprovedCpt,
    'Column 4': response[i].top5[j].text,
    'Column 5': response[i].top5[j].value,
  });
}
}
```

```
const sheetTitle = 'Sheet Title';sheets.push({ title: sheetTitle, data: dataRows });
```

```
const filters = {Timeperiod: filter1.timePeriod,Tin: payload.filter2.value || this.key,Npi: payload.filter3.value || this.key,Lob: payload.filter|| this.key,Channel: payload.channel || this.key,ServiceType: payload.serviceSetting || this.key,ServiceCategory: payload.ServiceCategory || this.key,};
```

```
this.downloadService.download({ sheets },{fileFormat: '.xlsx',fileName: 'abc',journeyName: 'def',metricName: 'ghi',filters,});}
```

Comment: This isn't related to Angular.  I would change your tags so that it is related to the library you are using.  Are you using exceljs?  Maybe tag it with that.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to point out what error you are getting if you are getting an error.